Permission Denied Error When Running Gradle Command on Server via Node.js Script
I have built a website that includes functionality for users to build .apk files. The process involves several steps:

Get a copy from the main default Android app for the specific user.
Allow users to copy their own assets into copied android project.
Build the app.


When building the app, my code executes a .bat file using the following command:
./gradlew --stacktrace --info assembleDebug assembleDebugUnitTest assembleDebugAndroidTest
Here is the relevant part of my code for executing the function:
const util = require("util");
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec);

await exec(`${andpath}\\assembleDebug.bat`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    process.chdir(originalDirectory);
    if (error) {
        console.log("error" + error);
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: "APK build failed" });
    } else {
        console.log("APK build successful");
        res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    }
});


This setup works correctly on my local machine. However, when I deploy it on the server, I encounter the following error:
errorError: Command failed: ./assembleDebug.bat

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: Permission denied

* Try:
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:113)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:96)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:91)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.readFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:41)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.get(SimpleStateCache.java:49)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.get(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:34)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getAll(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:71)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:120)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:145)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:99)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:167)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:259)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:230)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:82)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:30)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:96)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:40)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:44)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:41)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:361)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:34)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:35)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1043)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:152)
at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:110)
... 42 more

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org




When I try running the .bat file with ./gradlew --debug --scan assembleDebug assembleDebugUnitTest assembleDebugAndroidTest, I get the following error output:
errorError: Command failed: ./assembleDebug.bat
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] java.io.IOException: Permission denied
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
2024-05-21T15:27:06.859+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



Additional Information:

The server is running on Linux.
I am not using Android Studio IDE.
I have verified that the .bat file exists and is in the correct directory.
I have checked file permissions and they appear to be set correctly.
When I manually run the .bat file on the server terminal, it builds the APK successfully.
I have executed the command chmod -R +x ./androidproject.

Questions:
What could be causing this Permission denied error when running the Gradle command via the Node.js script on the server?
How can I resolve this issue to successfully build the .apk file on the server through the script?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
What I Have Tried:

Checking and adjusting file permissions.
Executing chmod -R +x ./androidproject.
Running the command manually on the server, which builds the APK successfully.


